Remove theme from Settings Sync on vscode
vscode has a Settings Sync option to sync all your settings.
I want to exclude syncing the selected Theme. So, when I select a theme, say Dark Theme, in my local vscode, it doesn't sync to https://github.dev, for example.
I use github.dev to navigate the repository in a different git branch, and my local vscode to make changes to the repository. If the theme is synced, I can't easily tell the difference between the two.

Is this what you're looking for? Can I exclude certain settings with VS Code built-in settings sync feature? (I don't use Sync myself, so sorry if this doesn't help.)

Based on your answer, your question is a duplicate of Can I exclude certain settings with VS Code built-in settings sync feature?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question to make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@wjandrea The solution on your link does not indicate the specific setting but any setting. I believe my question and answer provides information to other readers about what specific setting they need to add to "settingsSync.ignoredSettings" to stop syncing the theme such that they can have different themes on different vscode instances.

As hinted by @wjandrea in a comment
the solution is to add
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": ["workbench.colorTheme"]

to settings.json, which in my case is in Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json but you should be able to open it by pressing cmd + p typing open user settings.
With this, I can have a theme for my local vscode and another for my remote vscode (in the browser).
